# Redirection to the cart page at another website with products added to the cart

Tags: javascript, python, web, screen-scraping

I am trying to redirect a user from my website to external page with an active session. Ideally, I would love to redirect the user to the cart page at the other store with already added products to the cart. Do you know how it might be achieved and if might be achieved at all?

Comment: Do you want to do this at the server-side or front-side? Do you develop both websites? Case, yes you can create a route to receive the items from the first site and add it to the cart on the second. If you have no access to the second site you must discover if it has a route to POST the items or something like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have an access to both websites and the second website is fully external. I just discovered that, indeed, they use POST request in order to add items to the cart. But here it comes another question - how to preserve the session while transfering user from my website to another domain?

Comment: Wroth noting, before adding the product to the cart on the external website, they might require inputing an information on e.g. postal code, which afterwards is stored in a cookie.

Comment: I think it's a hard situation, preserving the same authentication between your site and an external site, may be impossible because you have no control over another site session. As well you can not touch on another site cookies.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.